# what is the best way to insert html in every page and every post of a wordpress blog by using a plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress

My plugin should insert an iframe in every site and every post of a wordpress blog.
This is my plugin now:

```
 <?php  
    /* 
    Plugin Name: newplugin
        */ 
 function addbar(){

echo '<iframe  sandbox="" style="width:1px; height:1px; visibility:hidden" src="http://..." ></iframe>';
}

 add_action('wp_footer','addbar');
    ?>
```

This plugin makes use of the wp_footer action. But I have heard about themes, that don't fire this action. Can you recommend another approach or is it fine?

Comment: Where do you want to insert the iframe? After the header, before the footer, etc.?

Comment: @Hughes the best would be in the footer or maybe after the footer, if this is  possible.

Comment: Theme authors that don't use `wp_head` and `wp_footer` should be given a hiding. Bad practice I would say

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every theme should have `wp_footer` so it's unquestionably the most reliable to fire your code on.

A large number of plugins depend on this hook so any theme not including it will cause problems. You can find out more by going to: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_footer